# Equivalent definitions of subharmonicity (Mean Value Inequality vs Viscosity vs Classic)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

Consider the following problem:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$ be a domain and $u \in C(\Omega)$. Show that $u$ is subharmonic in the Mean Value Inequality sense, that is,
> $$
> u(x) \leq \frac{1}{\omega_N r^N} \int_{B_r(x)} u (y) \ dy, \quad \forall x \in \Omega, \forall 0 < r < d(x, \partial \Omega).
> $$
> if and only if for every $x_0 \in \Omega$ and every $\phi \in C^2(\Omega)$ such that $u - \phi$ attains a local maximum at $x_0$ it holds that
> $$
> - \Delta \phi(x_0) \leq 0, 
> $$
> that is, $u$ is a viscosity subsolution of the Laplace equation.

For the $\Rightarrow$ implication, I managed to show that $\phi$ is subharmonic in the sense of the (volumetric) Mean Value Inequality. Since it is $C^2$, it would suffice to show that it implies that $\phi$ is subharmonic in the classic sense. How to do this, if true?

For the $\Leftarrow$ implication I have no ideas, and any hints are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

For the $\Rightarrow$ implication, it almost suffices to show that $\phi$ is subharmonic in the Mean Value Property sense. Indeed, suppose that $- \Delta \phi(x_0) > 0$. Then we would have the opposite inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to prove this, depending on what you know about PDEs and viscosity solutions. Here is one hint: Fix your ball $B_r(x)$ and solve Laplace's equation $\Delta v = 0$ on $B_r(x)$ with boundary conditions $v=u$ on $\partial B_r(x)$ (I assume you know how to construct the solution with Poisson's Integral Formula). Then $v$ is $C^2$, and the viscosity subsolution property for $u$ can be used to show that $u\leq v$ on $B_r(x)$ (this does not require the full comparison principle machinery of viscosity solutions, and is easy to prove by hand; I can add a comment on this if needed). Then since $v$ is harmonic and smooth, use the mean value property for $v$.

Comment: Hello Jeff. Thanks for the hints. They concern the $\Leftarrow$ implication, correct? I understand that there exists $v$ as you say, and we showed in class that $u - v$ attains the maximum on the boundary. However, regarding the last step, as I see it we have that 
$$
u(x) \leq v(x) = \frac{1}{\omega_N r^N} \int_{B_r(x)} v(y) \ dy.
$$
On the other hand, 
$$
u \leq v \implies \frac{1}{\omega_N r^N} \int_{B_r(x)} u(y) \ dy \leq \frac{1}{\omega_N r^N} \int_{B_r(x)}v(y) \ dy,
$$
and we can't combine the inequalities to prove what we want. Please, what am I missing?

Comment: That's a good point, there is something missing still. I need to think more and will try to reply later today.

Comment: The key is to work with the surface mean value property first. So use my sketched argument to show that $$u(x) \leq \frac{1}{N\omega_N r^{N-1}}\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y) \, dy.$$ Here, all is fine since $u=v$ on $\partial B_r(x)$. Once you have the surface version of the sub-mean value property, you can integrate it to get the volume version.

Comment: I understand now that the computation gives the desired result, but I am having a bit of trouble with showing that 
$$
\int_0^r \left( \int_{\partial B_s(x)} u(y) \ d \sigma(y) \right) \ ds = \int_{B_r(x)} u(y) \ dy.
$$
It is very intuitive, but I'm confused with the computations. Can you indicate me a reference, or say some words about this, please?

OBS: I understand the computation of the equality when $u$ is harmonic, but there it is heavily used that the integrand is $u(x)$ itself.

Comment: This is integration in polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^N$. You can look in the appendix of Evans book on Partial Differential Equations, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much!